# BTRFS restoring snapshot

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs, elementary-os, restore

I've installed Elementary OS on BTRFS then made a snapshot to /home/BACKUP. Now I've did some things and I have to restore that snapshot. I've tried to set the default subvolume to the snapshot with no result. Also as one tutorial suggested I should mount it then move the subvolumes so they change place. Well since mount mounts the root subvolume for me I can't do that. I've tried to mount using specifiying the volumeid then mounting them in two separate directories mount gave me "Directory not found error".

The list of subvolumes I currently have:

```
ID 257 gen 4244 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 4241 top level 5 path @home
ID 264 gen 3466 top level 5 path @home/BACKUP
ID 266 gen 4199 top level 5 path .snapshots
```

The snapshot is in read-write mode. How could I make @home/BACKUP and @ switch places?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmm... how do you have these subvolumes set up in /etc/fstab?